# Auto-updating a dependency repo when I update its dependent repo

Tags: svn, version-control, version, updates, svn-externals

We have a load of common third party assemblies in a separate repo to our development projects. This means that occasionally (around once a month), there are potential problems when some code in one of our projects calls a method in a newer assembly version in the assembly folder. If we could get the common folder to pull an update when an update of the dev project was pulled, it would solve the problem. I've looked into svn externals but it only seems to work where the local copy is inside your repo working copy folder, and will not accept relative paths of any kind. Does anyone know of any other ways to achieve this?

Just to be clear, we have two separate repos checked out as follows:

1. F:\dev\common (https://svn/common)
2. F:\dev\mynewproject (https://svn/mynewproject)

When I pull an update for 2, I want to automatically update 1.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Subversion externals can be linked to external independent repo-URL
2. In case of using externals without PEG-revision all changes in linked repo will be automagically reflected on update of master-repostory